# Why can't I see the Code Folding menu item in PyCharm Edu edition? (2022.2)

Tags: pycharm, folding

In other editors, I use code folding to collapse all of the functions in a file, but can't seem to get this option to show in PyCharm Education edition (2022.2). It should show under the "Code" main menu item, toward the middle. I have attempted to close and re-open the project I was working on, and the IDE, but to no avail.

Comment: Note for future searchers of this issue: Though I solved the issue with bad_coder's solution, the root cause may be cache related, and clearing it will help if so: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code folding options can usually be found in the the `Code` menu at the top of the IDE.

If for some reason they aren't showing see if they are set by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Apperance and Behavior` `>` `Menus and Toolbars` `>` `Main Menu` `>` `Code` `>` `Folding`, as show in the screenshot below.

If the Folding options you want are there but they still don't show in the menu, then try adding and removing them (don't forget to click `Apply` to commit the changes) to force the IDE to rewrite and reload [the configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html#location_of_directories).

[image: Main menu, code, in IDE settings]

Comment: Thank you for your help - Completely removing this menu item, clicking "Apply" in the Preferences/Settings modal, and then re-adding it, solved the issue.